# How to make java servlets in eclipse

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I'm currently trying to make servlets in eclipse using java. I just cant seem to find a good beginning tutorial for making them.. I have installed the neccesary plugins for eclipse and tomcat. I just don't know how it works and what's going on exactly.. :P

If anyone could explain it to me and give some examples or give links to some good beginning tutorials, i would really appreciate it ;)

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=eclipse+dynamic+web+project+tutorial

Comment: Start with [StackOverflow Servlets wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) that covers the basics of Servlets and provides tutorials with further explanation and even how to work with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "Dynamic Web Project". The resulting project should give you the options to add servlets to it just by right-clicking on it and selecting Servlet from the "Add" menu.

Running it is quite simple, too. When you first try to run your project ("Run on server"), it will ask you what server to use (Tomcat) and where your Tomcat is installed. And presto! your application runs on your Tomcat, and you can access it with your browser on `localhost:8080/myproject/myservlet`.

After that, virtually any tutorial you google should help you just fine.